# Converting Mutiple Fields to SIngle Fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am having this Pandas DataFrame

```
a     b        c            d           e           f            g
1   2022       11          12          13          14           15
2   2023       17          22          23          24           25
```

I want to convert this to

```
a     b        c 
1   2022       11
2   2022       12
3   2022       13
4   2022       14
5   2022       15
6   2023       17
7   2023       22
8   2023       23
9   2023       24
10  2023       25
```

What is the most optimized way to achieve?

Comment: Please show some code of your attempt at doing so

Answer (score 4):

I think this should be `melt` problem

```
newdf=df.melt(['a','b']).sort_values('b')
newdf
   a     b variable  value
0  1  2022        c     11
2  1  2022        d     12
4  1  2022        e     13
6  1  2022        f     14
8  1  2022        g     15
1  2  2023        c     17
3  2  2023        d     22
5  2  2023        e     23
7  2  2023        f     24
9  2  2023        g     25
```

If you need a here from 0 - n

```
newdf.a=newdf.index+1
```

Comment: @ W-B , you are awesome :-) +1

Comment: How you guys reproduce the dataFrame So quickly ?  is there a trick or just a matter of typing fast & Faster :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
df.drop('a', axis=1)\  # No need for the original 'a`
  .set_index('b')\ # Make 'b' the index
  .stack()\ # Convert from "broad" to "tall"
  .reset_index()\ # Convert the index back to a regular column
  .drop('level_1', axis=1)\ # Remove the residual original column names
  .rename({0: 'c'}, axis=1) # Rename the new column to 'c'
#      b   c
#0  2022  11
#1  2022  12
#2  2022  13
#3  2022  14
#4  2022  15
#5  2023  17
#6  2023  22
#7  2023  23
#8  2023  24
#9  2023  25
```